# stringWithUTF8string returns null

Tags: ios, utf-8

I tried to solve my issue for a week and the only hope is for You!
I receive from a user a string via uitextview and cast it using next code:

```
unsigned char* pAr = [myuitextview.text UTF8string];
```

Then after some work i want to show resulting pAr in the myuitextview using this code:

```
Myuitextview.text = [NSString stringWithUTF8string:pAr];
```

As result i see blank myuitextview. 
After investigation i discovered,that stringWithUtf8string returns `nil`, but i received it in utf8 and create back with utf8.
Then i discovered that UTF8string
returns nil also.
Also i discovered that it happens when i use unsigned char* instead of const char* returned by utf8string method. When i receive to const char* it returns a c string but if i try unsigned char* it returns nil.

What can be the reason of null after stringwithutf8string? As i understand Unsigned char * and const char* are safe casts?

Answer (score 1):

You can't so easily transfer unsigned char to NSString

Try this one

```
NSString* s = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:pAr length:sizeof(pAr) encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSString has a method "UTF8String" (note the use of caps")

I don't see a method "utf8string" (all lower case). Where does that method come from? (Objective-C method names are case sensitive, so those are differennt method names.)

Also, note that in the docs for UTF8String say:

The returned C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will certainly not have a longer lifetime. Therefore, you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you called this method.

If you use that method you meed to make sure that your text field sticks around and that you don't change it's string contents or the pointer you get back from the UTF8String method will become invalid.

Comment: Why UTF8string returns nil if i receive it in unsigned char* ,and returns correct c string if a pointer is char*?